# Concern Regarding JPA CrudRepository Save Method Under Heavy Load

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I read some similar questions before but couldn't extract a spot-on answer. The **save** method on **CrudRepository** interface checks if your entity already exists in the database. If the entity already exists in the database, it updates the corresponding row. Otherwise, it inserts a new row.

```
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

In either case, it needs to do two operations: Either select-update or select-insert. However, an application might have a lot of cases in which it only needs to make an insert or an update without an extra check whether the entry already exists or not. Therefore, unless it uses some internal optimization techniques, it should work slower in comparison with direct queries. Is my inference correct? Assume that your application works under a **heavy load**, with thousands of queries every second.

I also have a second question regarding the save operation. In standard SQL, **insert** and **update** queries are two separate operations. I don't quite understand why JPA merges these operations under a single **save** method without providing separate functionalities for different query needs. I'm working on a big application where I need to prevent inserting new entities into the database while only allowing update queries. I also have cases in which I only need to insert new entities into the database without needing an additional check whether the entities already exist or not. In order to stop people from performing unwanted operations, I want to update the standard behaviour of **CrudRepository** so that I can forbid inserting new elements but I couldn't achieve that so far.

I need some insights on the subject. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Checkout https://vladmihalcea.com/best-spring-data-jparepository/

Comment: This is exactly what my concern was, thanks.